# FB.getLoginStatus and FB.login how to use these methods in syncronized way?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, synchronization

```
function shareFB(){
    var status = 1;
    $(".inviteshare .sendingmsg").show();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.authResponse && response.status == 'connected') {              
            console.log('getloginstatus-exist');
            status = 0;
            fbShare();
            console.log(response);
        }
    },{scope:'publish_stream'});

    console.log('status:'+status);

    if(status == 1){
        FB.login(function(response){
            if (response.authResponse) {                
                console.log('new login');
            fbShare();
        }
        },{scope:'publish_stream'});
    }
    return false;
}
```

It returns two fbshare dialog popups.Because when i call a function it returns status = 1 (if i already logged in) .but if i already logged in it ll be return status =0 but here. the two js calls (FB.getLoginStatus and FB.login) runs asynchronize. how do solve this issue? FB.login() should nt run before i get the response from first call? how to do that?

Comment: What does your fbShare function do? If it is just calling one of the Facebook dialogs to let the user share - those don’t need any permissions, and therefor the user does not need to login to your app in the first place.

Comment: fbshare() does open a photo sharing dialog box FB.ui() .  Initially i want to check if user already logged in or not.. if logged it just call fbshare() for post data. else it call the FB.login() then it will open FB.ui (for open post share dialog).

Comment: What for? Again, those dialogs don’t need any permissions, so the user does not need to login to your app to use them in the first place. (And btw., the permission you are trying to ask for doesn’t even exist any more.)

Comment: i mean my function runs as asynchronize. i want to run as synchronize .

Comment: Again: Why do you want the user to login _at all_? It is not necessary, when you just use the dialogs to let them share.

Comment: thats right.. but my fuctionality does not works like that. do you have any reference for fix that issue?

Comment: Just remove all that login nonsense, and call the Share or Feed dialog as described in the docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Comment: oh... if i call share function it aurometically calls login function? (if it is not logged)

Comment: The dialogs will automatically prompt the user to log into Facebook, if they are not, yes. But that is something different than login to your app (which is what FB.login does; and yes, naturally that too brings up the Facebook login first, if the user is not already logged in to Facebook.)